# Difficulties calculating power towers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I seem to be having some troubles getting Excel to calculate power towers correctly.

If I type `=0.001^0.002^0.003` in a cell, Excel outputs the answer as `0.99995855` instead of the correct answer of `0.00113609`.

From what I can gather, Excel is interpreting `a^b^c` as `(a^b)^c` instead of the correct interpretation of `a^(b^c)`.

Is there anyway to fix this so Excel will handle scenarios like this correctly?

Comment: Useful: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~knill/pedagogy/ambiguity/index.html

Comment: @RobinMackenzie: Aussie is right here: `a^b^c` must be interpreted as `a^(b^c)`, the other interpretation is plain wrong, so Excel is plain wrong.

Comment: @Dominique - yeah sure agreed, just interesting the level of discussion there is around it. I'm proposing a VBA solution as a work around .

Comment: Another interesting item in the list below would be Ada, for which there are implementations which won't compile `x**y**z` and insist on parentheses - check line 132: https://gitlab.henlo.us/Rocketman173/henloOS/-/blob/3e57295cf28d30a8a3fe9865211543ef0817d6b7/cross-compiler/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/ada/par-ch4.adb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [blog post](https://codeplea.com/exponentiation-associativity-options) by [Lewis Van Winkle](https://github.com/codeplea) (referred to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Serial_exponentiation) as well) gives a useful breakdown of how different applications/ languages are handing this issue of left vs right associativity; where right-associative treatment of power towers is the correct approach. His table is:

| What | Code Tested | Result | Associativity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bash | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| C++ | `a^b^c` | 64 | left-associative |
| DuckDuckGo | `2^2^3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Excel | `2^2^3` | 64 | left-associative |
| EtherCalc | `2^2^3` | 64 | left-associative |
| Fortran | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Google | `2^2^3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Google Sheets | `2^2^3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Hand-held Calculators |  |  | Varies |
| Lua | `2^2^3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Matlab | `2^2^3` | 64 | left-associative |
| Octave | `2^2^3` | 64 | left-associative |
| Perl | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| PostgreSQL | `2^2^3` | 64 | left-associative |
| Python | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Ruby | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| Tcl | `2**2**3` | 256 | right-associative |
| WolframAlpha | `2^2^3` | 256 | right-associative |

To which we can add [r](/questions/tagged/r) in the right-associative camp.

Clearly right-associative is the dominant method of this sample which excludes other applications and languages that do not have a similar exponentiation operator (C#, SQL Server, Powershell etc). I'd hazard a guess that this issue is not 'fixed' in Excel (and the others) due to backward compatibility concerns.

It's probably not relevant here in this question (and it's way over my head) but there's a guy on Math Exchange saying that left-associative is the way for [ordinal tetration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2313576/341419) (see the comments).

Anyway my answer is to use a user defined function in VBA e.g. from a range:

```
Function POWTOWR(rng As Range) As Double
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim lng As Long
       
    var = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(rng.Value))
    dbl = 1
    For lng = UBound(var) To LBound(var) Step -1
        dbl = var(lng) ^ dbl
    Next lng
        
    POWTOWR = dbl
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    POWTOWR = CVErr(xlErrNum)
End Function
```

And from an array:

```
Function POWTOWA(ParamArray vals() As Variant) As Double
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim lng As Long
    
    Debug.Print TypeName(vals)
    
    dbl = 1
    For lng = UBound(vals) To LBound(vals) Step -1
        dbl = vals(lng) ^ dbl
    Next lng
        
    POWTOWA = dbl
    
    Exit Function
    
ErrHandler:
    POWTOWA = CVErr(xlErrNum)
End Function
```

Where `POWTOWR = CVErr(xlErrNum)` is handling results going bigger than the maximum for a Double type which according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1041458/what-is-largest-value-number-that-i-can-store-in-an-excel-vba-variable) is `1.79769313486231570x(10^308)` (my brackets :))

Results:

[image]

Comment: IMHO 11 out of 18 is a small majority, and in no way does that represent  _Clearly right-associative is the dominant method_.  Rather, it demonstrates that it is unwise to assume either left or right dominance.

Comment: @chrisneilsen fair point - I updated it to *Clearly right-associative is the dominant method of this sample which excludes other applications and languages that do not have a similar exponentiation operator (.NET, SQL Server, Powershell etc).* I was surprised there's nothing in C# to replicate this (unless I am wrong)

Comment: Bottom line: one should either _know_ the system ones using and rely on its implementation,  or, preferably, unambiguously specify what's intended using ()

Comment: @chrisneilsen clearly the OP *did not know* and is therefore asking... He's got 3 different options so far. Do you have a use case for the left-associative method btw ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apply BODMAS and put brackets to make sure Excel does what you expect.

BODMAS Brackets of Division Multiplication Addition Subtraction. Various versions of this are around.

And just for info the result of =000.1^(0.002^0.003) is 0.10434487
at least in my version of excel.

If the calculation is really "0.001^(0.002^0.003) the result is 0.00113609

And, just for a laugh, I used the standard system calculator on my mac and it needs the brackets same as above: "0.001^(0.002^0.003) for the same result 0.001136091498 with a few extra decimal places.

Comment: I think you miss understood my post. Excel is incorrectly applying the fundamentals of the standard order of operations. a^b^c should ALWAYS be interpreted as a^(b^c). The fact that Excel doesn't do this is honestly just unacceptable.

Comment: @AussieMathematician but I have a question here, did you mean "=000.1" or "0.001" as that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm afraid in Excel you must use parenthesis to make sure Excel does the steps in the right order. The formula `=0.001^(0.002^0.003)` returns the output you want.  *The fact that Excel doesn't do this is honestly just unacceptable* Then use another software in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `^` then you must use parenthesis to choose order resolution.

But if you use the function POWER, then Excel will calculate exactly as you wish.

The formula would be:

```
=POWER(0.001,POWER(0.002,0.003))
```

The output is 0.001136091

> [POWER
> Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/power-function-d3f2908b-56f4-4c3f-895a-07fb519c362a)

Comment: Just remember that some systems use "," not ";".

Comment: Yep, I forget about that all the time when copypasting ^^