# How do I use Excel Solver for exponents?

Tags: excel, solver, exponential, exponent

My equation is Q^Q^.25=6,512,786

I have the following input

[image]

And here is my solver
[image]

I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the [non-standard](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633790/294695) way that Excel handles iterated exponents. Excel parses `Q^Q^0.25` as `(Q^Q)^0.25`, which grows very rapidly. You probably intended `Q^(Q^0.25)`, which, while still growing rapidly, doesn't explode in the same way. If you change your equation in `D2` to

```
=C2^(C2^0.25)
```

and rerun the solver with the same settings (but a nonzero starting value at `C2` since `0^0` is undefined) you will get convergence, to approximately 117.44.

On Edit: It turns out that in the programming world there is a greater diversity of how associativity of exponentiation is handled than I realized. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68209996/4996248) to a related question contains an interesting table surveying how different programming languages handle it.